# C++ union element size based on other's element size

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct S
{
    union
    {
        int arr1[10];
        char arr2[sizeof(arr1)];
    };
};
```

It compiles successfully with gcc 4.9.2 in c++03 and c++11 mode. However when I change `S` to be a template like so:

```
template <size_t N>
struct S
{
    union
    {   
        int arr1[N];
        char arr2[sizeof(arr1)];
    };  
};
```

I get the following error output:

> `error: int S<10ul>::<anonymous union>::arr1 [10]’ is inaccessible`
>
> `int arr1[N];`
>
> `error: within this context`
>
> `char arr2[sizeof(arr1)];`

Clang compiles both versions only in c++11 mode. I am curious what is the correct behavior here. Maybe should I explicitly state that `arr2` size is `sizeof(int) * N`?

Comment: plus 1 for tricky C++ question

Comment: @djechlin I discovered that by accident :)

Comment: Your proposed solution does seem to solve the problem, though no idea why.

Comment: The code compiles... Can you post full code?

Comment: @amchacon What is your compiler? I have gcc 4.9.2 and template version does not compile. You have to instantiate the template to trigger the error.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot build one instance of S :)

Comment: [class.union]/5 states that "For the purpose of name lookup, **after the anonymous union definition**, the members of
the anonymous union are considered to have been defined in the scope in which the anonymous union is
declared." [emphasis mine] But what happens **within** the definition of the anonymous union?

Comment: Not that it says anything about being correct or not, but VS2013 don't compile either versions: `error C2327: 'S::arr1' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator` (with `'S<N>::arr1'` for the template version).

Answer (score 15):

Your union is anonymous. Thus, the compiler will create `arr1` and `arr2` at class-level.

Because of this, `char arr2[sizeof(arr1)];` won't refer to `arr1` properly.

Here is a workaround :

```
template <size_t N>
struct S
{
    union A
    {   
        int arr1[N];
        char arr2[sizeof(arr1)];
    };  
};
```

Compiles fine here : https://ideone.com/JcvOYg

By naming the union, we prevent the compiler from including it directly. It is then able to retrieve `arr1` properly.

But it also means that `arr1` and `arr2` aren't not `S`'s members anymore.

**Finally, `Members can be defined in terms of other members` but the latter has to be "findable" by the compiler.**

Comment: Similarly, `union { int arr1[N]; char arr2[sizeof(arr1)]; } u;` is accepted by g++ (note the final `u` as the name of the union object) So g++ has no issue with named nor unnamed unions, only with anonymous unions.

Comment: There is more than one possible solution. However the question is about whether some data members can be defined in terms of other members.

Comment: @piotrekg2 That's exactly what I tried to point out : `members can be defined in terms of other members` but the latter has to be "findable" by the compiler.

Comment: @Ninetainedo: agreed, it's a stronger assumption.

Comment: What about the non-template anonymous union version? Is that also outside C++11? Was the compiler being more permissive than strictly necessary in compiling it?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
template <size_t N>
class S
{
private:
    union
    {
        int arr1[N];
        char arr2[N*sizeof(int)];
    };
};
```

Comment: I did a test with char arr2[N*sizeof(decltype(arr1[0]))]; for if arr1 changed type and it didn't work with the union being anonymous :(  Just thought you should know.